# ReactJS - Problem when importing a utility function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this utility function:

```
export function myFunc(inputDate) {
    const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
    const dateString = `${inputDate}Z`;
    const localDate = new Date(dateString);

    const dataToExport = { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate }; 
    
    export default dataToExport
}
```

I'm using it in another file that imports it:

```
import { myFunc } from './Utils.js';
//...rest of the code ommited
<td>{myFunc(order.data.created_at)}</td>
//...rest of the code ommited
```

The function is being called in that part of the code. The following error message is returning:

> Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
>
> 6 |     const dataToExport = { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate
> };     7 |
>
> > 8 |     export default dataToExport
> > |     ^

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you want to `return` dataToExport from `myFunc` but still React would not accept an object as a child.

Comment: instead of returning something your function makes export default? may be it should return dataToExport instead and in another file you would grap this and use?

Comment: @Serj1c that would cause React to throw a `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because **Imports and exports must be at the top level**.
Your export default is in the function now. That's the reason.
Please check [here](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_basics-of-es6-modules)

You can change the code like this.

```
export function myFunc(inputDate) {
    const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
    const dateString = `${inputDate}Z`;
    const localDate = new Date(dateString);

    const dataToExport = { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate }; 
    
    return dataToExport;
}

<td>{myFunc(order.data.created_at).dateToString}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the dataToExport:

```
export function myFunc(inputDate) {
    const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
    const dateString = `${inputDate}Z`;
    const localDate = new Date(dateString);

    const dataToExport = { dateToTime, dateToString, localDate }; 
    
    return dataToExport
}
```

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys 
{dateToTime, dateString, localDate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in td (at Row.jsx:139)
    in tr (at Row.jsx:102)

Comment: I had copied your code and there appeared an error message above.

Comment: That is the point, you should understand what you are doing. If you do not get the point i think you should get familiar about how to work with javascript and json objects. The problem happens because you are passing a full json object to <td>. You should specify what attribute you want.